# is there a way to list external php extensions, and not these already compiled in php.exe?

Tags: php, php-extension

I know get_loaded_extensions() function but it spews a long list of things that are obvious. Maybe there is a way to filter out of this list extensions that are inside php.exe and leave only these really optional from external files and configured in php.ini ?

Answer (score 3):

Not really. PHP doesn't make a difference between compiled in and extensions loaded via php.ini (extensions loaded via `dl()` can be identified using `ReflectionExtension::isTemporary()`)

What you can do is compare the outpout of `php -m` and `php -nm`. The `-m` option lists all extensions (modules), `-n` doesn't load any php.ini and therefore no external extension.